# Windows batch script runs twice

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a batch script which redirects to a log file using the following line:

```
call :START 1>>%Log_File% 2>>&1
```

Redirecting to the file works fine.  However, once the script completes, it runs again and displays to console.
I confirmed that only after the script completes and outputs to the log file, it runs again and outputs to screen (it run for about an hour, so it is noticeable and there are timestamps in the output).

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: probably, this line is part of a script and followed by the label `:Start`. After calling the label, the script continues to run. Place a `goto :eof` before the `:Start` label.

Comment: @Stephan, write your comment as a formal answer so it can be used better by others.

Comment: @YoavK, going forward please provide all relevant code in your question. Since you are calling out to a label we would really need to see all the code between the call and the end of the code in the label.

Answer (score 4):

probably, this line is part of a script and followed by the label `:Start`. After calling the label, the script continues to run. Place a `goto :eof` before the `:Start` label.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, I was able to solve it, by adding the line above under the invoking line

```
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

And it is worked for me(I not quite sure at all if this is the right way).

Comment: there is no such thing as "**the** right way". It all depends on your needs.`Goto :eof` and `exit /b` both end the script. `Exit /b` additionally can return an errorlevel, which may be useful in some use cases.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan for the further explanation :)